# Files and Folders - all new created or changed show dates one hour after system time!

Tags: datetime

This is Magento 1.9.2.4. Here is the current situation:

1. Server time is correctly set up. I can check it from Terminal.
2. PHP time is correctly set up as timezone. I created a php file for showing the date.
3. Time for Magento frontend is correctly set up. I can check it in any phtml template.
4. In Magento database time for Created At and Updated At fields are UTC time

Here is my issue:

In Magento file system all changes to files or folder show a time one hour after system time. I deleted the files in /var/cache then reload the frontend and current system time/Magento is 14:42 and files were created 15:42. "Someone" is adding one hour to every file/folder created or changed. I uploaded a product image again 1 hour after system time.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. This issue is coming from WinSCP. If you get this issue use this solution: in "Login" window after filling up all your server information click on [Advanced ...] button. In "Advanced Site Settings" window click on Environment and in section "Daylight saving time" choose "Preserve remote timestamp". Now login to your server and dates should be listed correctly.